# What's the event for leaving the IE tab?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I want my javascript to be trigged when:

- The current IE tab is **switched** out when multiple IE tabs are open.
- When the current IE tab is **closed**.
- **I don't want my JS code be trigged by the *in-page* pops up dialogs.**
- When the whole IE window closed.

The **lose focus** event may not work for me because there are pop up diaglogs in my page, so when it pops out, the IE tab will lose focus, but since the tab is not **switched** or **closed**, I don't want my javascript to be trigged here.

Is there any solution? I am wondering if there's something like ***entering tab*** / ***leaving tab***, or ***tab-switching*** events?

Some interesting links, but not resolve my question.

[Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

[Hook into tab changed event of browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436215/hook-into-tab-changed-event-of-browser)

Comment: To JS, tabs and windows are the same thing. It can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

if you use 'jQuery', you can easily do it .

```
$(window).blur(function(){
  // your code 
});
$(window).focus(function(){
  // your code
});
```

here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) which provides one more method to do it.

Comment: jquery that is cheating the guy is using javascript. :D

Comment: I am afraid this cannot handle the in-page pop-up dialog. The focus will fall on the dialog box, so the blur event will be raised for the window/tab. But I don't want it to be raised.

Comment: true, this will not work for inpage popups :( , there are two more events 'onbeforeunload' 'onunload' try putting these on body tag.. i hope this will work..

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in

```
(function(){

    function doOnFocus(){ console.log("focus"); }
    function doOnBlur(){ console.log("blur"); }
    function doOnLeave(){ console.log("leave"); }

    if('onfocusout' in document){
        document.onfocusout = doOnBlur;
        document.onfocusin = doOnFocus;
    }else{
        window.onblur = doOnBlur;
        window.onfocus = doOnFocus;
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = doOnLeave;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is an event on window close it is not IE specific but is mostly used to call an alert before the user leaves the page. It's one of my pet peeves and is very annoying but may be what you are looking for.

window.onbeforeunload = yourfunctionthatexecutes;